# naming an ajax tab

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

Simple question (I hope) I have a series of jQuery tabs, some of which are ajax calls:

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="#item">Item</a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="specLi"><a href="#spec">Spec</a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="productionLi"><a href="ajaxProduction.aspx?itemId=<%=itemId %>"><span>Production</span></a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="qualLi"><a href="ajaxQuality.aspx?itemId=<%=itemId %>"><span>Quality</span></a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="customersLi"><a href="#customers"><span>Customers</span></a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="salesLi"><a href="ajaxSales.aspx?itemId=<%=itemId %>"><span>Sales</span></a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="suppliersLi"><a href="#suppliers"><span>Suppliers</span></a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="purchasesLi"><a href="ajaxPurchases.aspx?itemId=<%=itemId %>"><span>Purchases</span></a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="stockLi"><a href="ajaxStockMovement.aspx?itemId=<%=itemId %>"><span>Stk Movt</span></a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="NotesLi"><a href="#notes"><span>Notes</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

I would like to link to specific tabs using an #anchor - which works fine. However for the Ajax tabs I can't specify the #anchor name. In the rendered html i get ui-tabs-1 ui-tabs-2 etc

Is there a way to specify the anchor text after the #?

Thanks in advance

Gordon

[update]
Got it, just needed to add a name="linkname" to the a tag

Comment: do you want to add `#name` to every `a` which are not having that?

Comment: I can link to the specified anchors i.e. page.html#spec but for the ajax pages I dont know what the #name is

Comment: Got it, just needed to add a name="linkname" to the a tag

Comment: I would like to custom name my ajax tabs as well, because I'm using this to make them bookmarkable:

    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        location.hash = ui.newPanel.selector;
    },

Do you know a way to custom name the ajax tabs to make it work with this?

Comment: Found out how.  I just use the aria-controls attribute on the li element to custom name a tab loaded via ajax

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add `name` to the `a` tag you can have something like this.

Doc: [$.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(function(){

   $("ul li a").each(function(){  //just limiting to all anchors inside the list

         $(this).attr("name","add some name to it");

   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){    
   $("ul li a").each(function(){
         name=$(this).attr("href");
         $(this).attr("name",name);//this will set the href attribute of element to name attribute    
   });    
});
```